# How do i send a set of keys to my program to implement using code only no keyboard C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, sendkeys

How do i implement a set of keys that have been sent to me by another program , for example **(Alt & F4)** or any other wanted *sequence* ? , **Thanks in Advance :)**

Comment: What kind of application are we speaking about? And is it specifically about "alt + f4", to prevent closing your application? A little bit more details would be very handy to be able to answer your question better (more accurate for what you want).

Comment: also, "implement"? I wonder if the word you are looking for is "scan" or "parse" or "view". Is your application using win forms? wpf? console? other?

Comment: You cannot implement a set of keys but you can implement a method that does something with a set of keys.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes yes you can using SendKeys check my post below

Comment: What I said was, that you are using the word "[implement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implementation)" in a wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to every one Turned out ,C# makes available a static class to do this:

```
SendKeys.Send("ABC");
```

this will send to the top most form ABC and for more keys check this link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx